# how should i run a java program from a php page,on submitting a form?

Tags: java, php, html

i ve a .php page and now i want to run a java program in the backend after submitting a form in php.i ve tried using exec(), system() functions and sadly its not working. please help me out.
This is the code snippet:

```
if($_POST["ADD"])
{
        echo "Phrase has been added now"."<br />";
        $lastline=exec("java -Dwordnet.database.dir=D:\wordnet\2.1\dict Process",$retval); 
}
```

Process is my main class which I want to be executed.

Comment: ya it works from the command prompt but not from a php page.

Comment: THe user your Apache (or whatever you use) server is using needs to have execute privileges for java.

Comment: @Sanjay, beware of any malicious code a user can inject in '$retval', incase the post parameter values are not sanitized. This would be a huge security concern on a public facing site.

Answer (score 1):

First, you posting an error message would have been helpful. Checking the **return code** is also wise.

Second, specify the full path to java, e.g. `/usr/bin/java` instead of just using `java`.

Comment: actually the java program is used to update a database but its not getting updated. i tried giving the full path but the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Start the java process in debug mode i.e. with jdwp enabled. Then connect to the java process with some debugger for example jdb but better use full fledged IDE like Eclipse.
Make sure you set suspend flag to y otherwise the java process will terminate before you are able to establish debug session to it

```
exec("java -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9002,server=y,suspend=y <the rest of command>")
```

A somewhat simple solution is to use logging in you java app, configured to write to some file, so that you can check whats going wrong during execution.

Btw, are you sure that the java program is actually getting executed? :)

Comment: The java program executes perfectly.